# Disable Lint error in Plato tool

Tags: javascript, testing, plato

I am using [Plato](https://github.com/es-analysis/plato) to analyse java script code, But I want to disable lint error for my code during analyse. How can I do that with out touching code is there way or do I have to dig in code.